# Searching static data using Windows Search Service with IIS

Tags: windows, search, iis, asp-classic

I have a website made with classic asp, using the Indexing Service to make fulltext search on static pages.  This website is running on Windows Server 2003, and we are migrating to Windows Server 2012. On Windows Server 2012, the Indexing Service is no longer supported, so I have to migrate it to use Microsoft Search Server Express.

I found many docs about get search static pages within a website using Indexing with Internet Information Services. Although this docs says that the Indexing Service is no longer supported, there are no references on how to do it with Microsoft Search Server Express - the "new" searching solution.

Does anybody knows where I can find some docs about it?